# How to get the Message-ID of an email sent via Gmail API without using read scopes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail-api

I fully understand the procedure for sending threaded replies via the Gmail API and can do so successfully by appending the `Message-ID` to the `In-Reply-To` and `References` headers.

The problem is the way I get the MIME `Message-ID` is by fetching the thread via its immutable `id` in a separate API call (using `Users.messages get`). So my current flow for sending a threaded reply is to take the original message/thread, read the metadata from that message via the API, retrieve the MIME `Message-ID`, append it to the headers of my new reply, and then it gets sent via the API.

I would like to only use the `gmail.send` scope in my app -- readonly/metadata are restricted scopes and Gmail wants us to pay up to $75,000 for a security assessment, *just so I can send threaded replies*.

I assumed I would just have what I need in my response after I sent the email, but I only get a response such as:

`{"id"=>"16c5xyzxyzxyz", "threadId"=>"16c5xyzxyzxyz", "labelIds"=>["UNREAD", "SENT", "INBOX"]}`

Something feels wrong here, **how do I retrieve the MIME `Message-ID` for an email I've sent through the API?**. I've looked all over SO and Google Docs, it feels like I'm missing something very obvious or people just assume these extra scopes are accessible, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### The message is located in the header of the message, you can retrieve it with `Users.messages: get` - it is located inside `payload.headers`.

- Before you write your function in Ruby, I recommend you to test your
  request with [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) to get familiar with the hierarchy of
  the [Users.messages resource representation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages):

[image]

- **The message-Id will be in the 'headers' part of the response:**

---

[image]

- The scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly` is sufficient to obtain this response. However, should you need a wider scope for a different feature of your code - you can use `https://mail.google.com/`.

  This is the information you can retrieve from the response when **sending** a message:

[image]

Comment: I'm already using User.messages `get` to retrieve this data, the problem is the readonly scope is a restricted scope, which requires a full security assessment, which requires lots of money. Is there really no way to get the message ID from the email we send via User.messages `send`? That one only requires a sensitive scope review, which does not require tens of thousands of dollars.

Comment: I updated my answer with the response you can expect for sending an e-mail. Unfortunately, it does not give you the message-ID. But I am not aware of any restrictions or payments requirements when it comes to the use of the 'read-only' scope. Just use it!

Comment: @ziganotschka Assuming OP is developing a user-facing app, he is therefore bound by a host of (relatively) new restrictions recently imposed by Google. Given that gmail's read-only scope is now considered a restricted scope OP's app will need to under go a security assessment for which he will need to pay between 15K to 75K... [See documentation](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#restricted-scopes)

Comment: I see. I was not aware that OP was planing to publish the app for public access. Should he wish to publish it on GSuite Marketplace for domain-wide installation only - there won't be any security assessments.